# Why all the System.* NuGet packages when getting Akka.Net?

Tags: .net, nuget, akka.net

When I install NuGet package Akka.Net a whole bunch of Microsoft System packages are downloaded and installed as package. System.IO e.g.

All those packages are probably available in .NET Framework 4.6.1 and I wonder why Akka.Net does not assume that there is a certain .NET Framework already in place.

Is it because Akka.Net wants to be platform independant so to speak?

Is it possible to tell Akka.Net to use a .NET Framework in place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the dependencies you will see

> .NETFramework 4.5
>
> - Newtonsoft.Json (>= 9.0.1)
> - System.Collections.Immutable (>= 1.3.1)

If you then check the dependencies for `System.Collections.Immutable` you will see the current version (1.4.0) does not have a `.NETFramework 4.5` section, this causes all those extra files to be downloaded because it has to treat it as a net-standard application.

If you get the package `System.Collections.Immutable` version 1.3.1 manually first, that version has a `.NETFramework 4.5` section. If you have the 1.3.1 version installed it should not try to grab the 1.4.0 version anymore.

You also could change your Dependency Behavior in your NuGet settings to get the Lowest numbered dependency or to the highest patch version (the 3rd number is the patch version), you likely have yours set to Highest or Highest Minor

[image: enter link description here]